# Markdown parsing/pre-processors - support for enhancing/modifying arbitrary markdown files

Tags: python, markdown

I am trying to take `.md` files from the file system and prepare them for Vuepress-based hosting.  To do that, I want to remain in markdown format, adjust some of the file contents, and save it to a differently-named `.md`.  The original file should remain as is on the file system and should remain viewable on the workstation.

Vuepress's build system can take care of `.md` => `.html` transformations, this is a step I want to avoid.

I've looked at [mistune](https://github.com/lepture/mistune) and [Python-markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/) but both seem a lot more interested in rendering the Markdown to HTML, a step I want to leave entirely up to Vuepress.

Is there some mode in either to a) read markdown b) modify it via user plugins c) **write it back as Markdown**?  What about non-Python utilities?  I can handle JS or Ruby, though nowhere as well as Python.

For example:

#### Vuepress uses Frontmatter (YAML) to qualify what's in a document.

```
---
title: Blogging Like a Hacker
lang: en-US
---
```

I want to add them to the front of the file.

#### Image links need updating

Let's say I have an image in the same directory as the `.md` file.  Markdown viewers can easily display using the markup below.

```
### My image:

![](./02.issue.png)
```

However, the following things need to happen for Vuepress to work:

```
### My image:

![](/<slug-based-name-for-md-file>/02.issue.png)
```

where `slug-based-name-for-md-file` is a unique name for the .md

and the file `02.issue.png` needs to be copied to `.vuepress/public/<slug-based-name-for-md-file>/02.issue.png`.

So, what I need is a *hook* to process every image reference in the markdown document.  I can write it easily, what I am looking for is a parser that tells me what images exist in a markdown file.

Yes, I know that finding images is only a few regexes away, but we do have those big powerful Markdown parsers so I wonder if I've missed something in their documentation.  Plus, more nested Markdown structures might not be easy to classify via regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> seem a lot more interested in rendering the Markdown to HTML

This is correct. That is what a Markdown parser does; convert Markdown to HTML.

However, a subset of Markdown parsers are implemented with a two-step process wherein step one parses the Markdown to an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and step two renders that AST to HTML. Generally, the second step can be replaced with an alternate renderer which could output a different format. If a Markdown renderer exists, then you could output Markdown from the AST. Some implementations which do this are mistune (Python) and marked (JavaScript), among others. However, AFAIK, neither come with Markdown renderer so you would either need to find a third party renderer or build your own.

Assuming a third party Markdown renderer exists, you can then subclass it and override the relevant parts. For example. using mistune, you could [customize](https://mistune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#customize-renderer) a theoretical Markdown renderer to alter the image elements like this:

```py
from somelib import MdRenderer

class CustomRenderer(MdRenderer):
    def image(self, src, alt="", title=None):
        src = get_link(src)
        return super().image(self, src, alt, title)
```

Note that the image `src` is modified by a function `get_link`. You will need to create that function or possibly make the modifications inline. You will also need to adjust the import statement according to the lib you find.

To use your custom renderer do this:

```py
markdown = mistune.create_markdown(renderer=CustomRenderer())
output = markdown(input)
```

If you were to create your own Markdown renderer it might look something like this:

```py
from mistune.renderers import BaseRenderer

class MdRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    NAME = 'md'

    # other elements defined here

    def image(self, src, alt="", title=""):
        src = get_link(src)
        if title:
            title = f' "{title}"'
        return f'![{alt}]({src}{title})'

    # other elements defined here
```

Of course, you will need to define methods for every type of element within a Markdown document.

Note that I used Python [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) in my example, which require a more recent version of Python. You may need to adjust if using an older version.

Comment: Those hand-rolled regexes look a lot more attractive all of a sudden :-)  I’m going to accept this, because you’ve told me I can stop looking at parsers for now.  Strange though, it seems to me automatically enhancing/annotating markdown itself before a final stage to html could occasionally be useful.  Maybe as a step to inject things like doxygen-based annotations in documentation.

Comment: @JLPeyret which path did you go down with this - using a markdown processor to modify the markdown file or did you use regexes? Thanks.

Comment: @jim70 regexes.  it's too bad the processors really don't seem to be targetting this.  Using regexes isn't that complicated in most cases but it is a bit brittle - i.e. it's easy to see how changing the format a bit would break hand-tuned regexes.

Comment: @JLPeyret Thank you for your comment. Will see what I can do with that. I am thinking that it might make sense to convert the Markdown into HTML and then extract portions from the Markdown file, and if I need to write something in place, then might make sense to modify in HTML and then convert back to Markdown. Regexes are intimidating and as you said, brittle.